# Create a bootable Ubuntu USB from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I have an iso image of 16.04 on a 2 GB stick.  I have tried several different ways to make it a bootable image. I'm running 14.04 and all the posts I find about this seem to be about how to use Windows to make a bootable stick. Can someone please explain to me how to make a 16.04 bootable stick using Ubuntu rather than Windows?

Comment: Who said anything about wanting to make a startup disk? The question is a duplicate, but not of that post.

Comment: its not a duplicate question because the ones posted dont work and dont answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

mkusb will make any sort of bootable image you want, Live USB, Persistent USB, and can be used to make a Full install USB that works on BIOS and UEFI.

mkusb will make a drive with boot partition(s), a read only ISO9660 OS partition, a ext2 casper-rw persistence partition and a NTFS Linux/Windows data partition.

[mkusb - tool to create boot drives | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

You can also do a Full install to USB similar to a HDD install. Best to disconnect your HDD before proceeding.